# How to construct the RecyclerView for the following UI vertically?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile, android-viewpager

The expected UI for my application should look like this:

[image: Main Trip]

I have thought about using a view pager but I cannot figure out how to change opacity of the next items or make the item in view to be centered and be elastic.

I have researched multiple open source GitHub repos and found two which seems similar to what I have approaching to do.

1. https://github.com/bloderxd/deck
2. https://github.com/Ramotion/garland-view-android

I do not know how to solve the problem of opacity or going to the next item using the next button in the UI (which was designed by me for a project).

So far, I could only create a simple XML representation of the UI without the view pager but I do not know what other libraries and views I need to implement to make it interactive and elastic like in the UI.

My request is how I could build the application level code for this UI. If there is any other obscurities in my questioning, feel free to comment and reach out because I am relatively new to this kind of development. Thank you.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but you want to build a vertical flow where the user first interact with the first CardView, after that tap on "Next", the list with cards is scrolled up and 2nd CradView is shown in the center of the screen? Something like this?

Comment: @MrVasilev Yes, exactly that. Sorry I couldn't explain it properly but yes, the CardView would contain data fields like a number slider or a drop-down menu and upon user input, it will move to the next CardView once the user clicks next.

Comment: In this case to me sounds more like non-scrollable RecyclerView with several custom ViewHolders and when the user tap "Next" you will scroll the RecyclerView manually to the next position.